# How do I access $NAME variable in a if else statement?

Tags: javascript, html, gis, arcgis-js-api

You can find the code in the link below.

[Sample running Code](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/renderer_class_breaks.html)

`${NAME}` in the infoTemplate displays County name.

I want to add a alert box which displays the county name. I can create a alert box but not able to display the county name.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Answer to the above question helps me to go further in my work. The main thing i want to know is how to access county name?

Comment: Show the relevant code in the question, not just a link to it.

Comment: alert("${NAME}"); /*this should display county name but it is not working for me...... */
                                                                                                                  var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("${NAME}", "${*}");     /*It dispalys County name  .....*/                             
           var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3", {
          mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
          outFields: ["*"],
          infoTemplate: infoTemplate
        });

Comment: alert("${NAME}"); /*.................I want the county name to be displayed here but it is not working for me.......*/                           var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("${NAME}", "${}");  /*It dispalys County name .....*/

Comment: You need to put all that in the question, where it can be properly formatted, not in the comments. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Add your non-working code from next time.. so that we can understand clearly

Comment: "${NAME}" is the syntax of arcgis api... i mean alert doesnt understand this format unless you add any string substitution method with it...

Comment: As currently presented the question provides next to no context, problem statement, nor any other characteristics of a [good StackOverflow question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: The actual theme of the question is to access the $NAME variable outside the infoTemplate and I will share you my answer in a while..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can access $NAME outside the infotemplate in the following way...
var t = "**${NAME}**

---

Incidents:";+inc // String substitution method 
var content = esriLang.substitute(evt.graphic.attributes,t);

Answer (score 0):

well, to show alert you have to attach click event on the feature or you have to use any event to propagate alert message.
In Above sample url I used feature layer click event to show "NAME" in the alert.

**Below is the working code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples 
      on iOS devices-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Class Breaks Renderer</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map{
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/"></script>
    <script>
      var map;
      require([
        "esri/map", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/InfoTemplate", "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol", 
        "esri/renderers/ClassBreaksRenderer",
        "esri/Color", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        Map, FeatureLayer,
        InfoTemplate, SimpleFillSymbol, 
        ClassBreaksRenderer,
        Color, domStyle, on
      ) {
        map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "streets",
          center: [-98.215, 38.382],
          zoom: 7,
          slider: false
        });

        var symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol();
        symbol.setColor(new Color([150, 150, 150, 0.5]));

        // Add five breaks to the renderer.
        // If you have ESRI's ArcMap available, this can be a good way to determine break values.
        // You can also copy the RGB values from the color schemes ArcMap applies, or use colors
        // from a site like www.colorbrewer.org
        //
        // alternatively, ArcGIS Server's generate renderer task could be used
        var renderer = new ClassBreaksRenderer(symbol, "POP07_SQMI");
        renderer.addBreak(0, 25, new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([56, 168, 0, 0.5])));
        renderer.addBreak(25, 75, new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([139, 209, 0, 0.5])));
        renderer.addBreak(75, 175, new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([255, 255, 0, 0.5])));
        renderer.addBreak(175, 400, new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([255, 128, 0, 0.5])));
        renderer.addBreak(400, Infinity, new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([255, 0, 0, 0.5])));

        var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("${NAME}", "${*}");
        var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3", {
          mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
          outFields: ["*"],
          infoTemplate: infoTemplate
        });

        featureLayer.setDefinitionExpression("STATE_NAME = 'Kansas'");
        featureLayer.setRenderer(renderer);
        map.addLayer(featureLayer);
        on(featureLayer, "click", function(evt){
          alert(evt.graphic.attributes.NAME)
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

In this code i have used above sample code with feature layer click event.

Hope this will help you :)

Let me know if any clarifications required !

Comment: plz share your approach on this portal that can be useful to others too.   :)